# Opening a specified folder and then highlighting does not work on Windows 7

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to open a folder, then highlight the folder with VBA code

```
Shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & SvAs &""",vbNormalFocus", vbNormalFocus"
```

The SvAs's value is `D:\letter123`.

It works, I've tried it on Windows 10 and MS Excel 2021 pro with that code.

But, when I tried using it on Windows 7, MS Excel 2019 pro, it didn't work.

I tried the alternative with followhyperlink, it works.

But, I don't really like this method, because it doesn't even highlight the folder.

Can anyone help with this problem? Or does anyone have the same problem as this?

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of `highlight the folder`.

Comment: open the "D:/" partition, then highlight the folder "letter123"

Comment: `Shell "explorer.exe /select,""" & SvAs & """,vbNormalFocus"` this works for me.